Why, when conductors are connected in series, their current strength is equal?
Why, when conductors are connected in series, their current strength is equal, because the resistivity of the conductors can be different?

What do you mean by "current strength"?  Magnitude?  Density?  Current density doesn't have to be the same for circuit elements in series.

Vladislav, There is a very nice poster made by the two authors of my favorite undergrad physics book, Matter & Interactions. It's here. Surface charge gradients set themselves up very quickly -- nanoseconds -- to provide just the right fields at just the right places so that it works out. You also may wish to read something a little more technical from the same two authors -- who specialize in computational physics -- here.

Vladislav, The bottom line is that if you tack-welded or soldered a tiny 30 gauge solid wire to the center of the large cut surface from a 2 gauge solid wire, each of some length, and then applied a voltage across the two remaining open ends, the sea of conduction band charges in both copper wires (unimaginable numbers) would start to move. But their surfaces would experience just the right charge gradients so as to propel the central, inner charges through both wires to yield a constant current. This would NOT be at a constant linear velocity in both wires, though!!! Get that straight.

Vladislav, Also? Definitely watch this video. A LIGO electronics engineer participates as a physics and electronics advisor with a YouTube author in a large scale experiment to show you some details that may also help you. I don't know of a better video to watch for this topic. Best wishes!

@Vlad, About 8 1/2 minutes into the video, which by the way also refers to Chabay and Sherwood -- the authors of the book I mentioned -- you will see a similar example that I mentioned, tacking a thin wire to a thick wire. Everything is about fields. And in a very sad way, the right way to think is held back from most of us during the early years while learning the lumped versions which only tell us a few things, all of which is actually totally wrong about how the universe really does work. The video is top-notch.

Not only conductors. This logic applies to anything: insulators, vacuum, plasma, whatever.
The reason lies in the conservation of charge, which is a principle deeply rooted in physics. The charges carrying the current through a surface will come out the other side of that surface.

Perhaps a water pipe analogy is in line.
If you have two pipes with different diameters connected in series, will the flow rate (liters/minute, gal/minute) be different in each section if there are no leaks? The flow rate will be the same in each section of the pipes.
Same goes for electrical conductors in series. The current, \$ I = {Q \over t} \$. in each conductor will be the same since the amount of charge transferred over time will be the same in each section of the conductors.

Because the electrons have nowhere else to go.
If you think about electricity as the physical movement of electrons, then in a DC circuit all of the mobile electrons enter at one end of the two joined conductors, go through the first one, go through the junction of the two wires (wire nut, solder, connector pins, whatever) and go through the second conductor returning to the power source.  If one of the two conductors is significantly smaller (higher resistance), that will throttle back the electron flow for the entire circuit.
In a series circuit, no matter how many components, or types of components, or wires, 100% of the current goes through 100% of the components 100% of the time.  The component types have a major effect on the electron flow, such as a capacitor blocking DC, but that is included in the rule.  Even if the capacitor has a very small leakage current, that tiny current moves through the other components.
Also, in a parallel circuit, 100% of the voltage appears across 100% of the components 100% of the time.

1 amp is equal to 1 colomb's worth of electrons passing a given point in a second.  1 coulomb is about 6x10¹⁸ electrons.
If the two wires are in series, then the current in the two must be the same.  If it wasn't, then either electrons would be piling up at the point where the wires meet, or else electrons would be magically appearing out of nowhere.  This is expressed more formally as Kirchhoff's current law.

"piling up" does indeed occur, that's what a capacitor describes

@BenVoigt yes, but it's accompanied by an "emptying out" of charges on the other plate, so to an observer with access only to the capacitor's terminals, it seems as if there's no piling up.

The current through the conductors is going to be determined by the total resistance, which you get by adding together the resistance of each conductor.
Moreover, what we see using Ohm's law, is that the total applied voltage is distributed across each conductor in proportion to its resistance.  So the conductor with more resistance will have a higher voltage across it, and that higher voltage will "push harder against" the higher resistance resulting in the same flow of current as the others.

Kirchoff's Current Law isn't restricted to ohmic devices.

I like to think that once we can understand simple electric circuits, then we're ready to move on to more advanced concepts like plumbing :)

Circuits with only ohmic devices are generally not very interesting.  In even my "simple" circuits, I usually like to include a voltage or current source.
